# Is it possible to set the last compatible version again in app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a couple of questions to be asked .

(1).Since the last compatible version of the app cannot be updated , How is it possible to  fix any issues with that version ?

(2).Can i change the last compatible ios version again and again or is it fixed ?

kindly try to answer them and clear my doubts . Thank you in advance.

Comment: People who can only run the older version of your app are stuck with that version.  You can't change it. You can release a new version of your app that supports older versions of iOS than your current release.

Comment: Yes . And imagine there is some issue with that app , and I want to fix that . How wud it be possible ? may be release another update for all the versions with bug fixes and then setting the last compatible version again ?

Comment: Let's say your current version is 2 and only supports iOS 8 and up and you have an older version still available, version 1, that supports iOS 6 & 7. If you now release version 3 with support for iOS 7 and up then iOS 6 users will still be on version 1 but iOS 7 and up can get version 3

Comment: fair enough . Now if I again want to set the compatible version to ios 8 with a version 4 , ios 7 wud be working fine with version 3 and ios 6 wud be working fine with version 1 right ?

Comment: perfect ! should there be a minimum time duration between two updates ?

Comment: No.  Apple will work on their own schedule, but there's nothing prohibiting you from submitting the next version as soon as the previous is Ready for Sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by last compatible version, you mean the Deployment Target setting used to build the submission (and the OS version against which, in best practices, you actually tested on some test device), you can, at any time, submit an update with a Deployment Target as low as iOS 6.0 (the lower limit that can be built by Xcode with the required arm64 slice).  With any update submission, you can build with a Deployment Target setting either higher or lower than whatever is the current compatibility setting, so you can alternate last compatible version if you wish (and Apple approves all the updates).